# Excel.Worksheet.Cells has reversed behavior?

Tags: c#, excel, transpose

Hey all, I'm experiencing transposed behavior when working the Excel.Worksheet.Cells array.

My first cell needs to be at **[row = 10, column = 3]**
My second cell needs to be at **[row = 11, column = 17]**

Then using these two cells as boundaries, I create a range and merge it.
As you can tell from the values noted above, the range should be mostly horizontal.

So, to help me out, I created a simple helper function that merges cells:

```
    public static void MergeRange(Excel.Worksheet worksheet, int startRowIdx, 
        int startColIdx, int endRowIdx, int endColIdx, bool across = false)
    {   //Get range boundaries.
        Excel.Range cells = worksheet.Cells;

        //commented out, resolved code is directly below - N. Miller, 9-24-2013
        //Excel.Range topleftCell = cells[startColIdx][startRowIdx];
        //Excel.Range bottomrightCell = cells[endColIdx][endRowIdx];
        Excel.Range topleftCell = cells[startRowIdx, startColIdx];
        Excel.Range bottomrightCell = cells[endRowIdx, endColIdx];

        //Merge range.
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("({0}, {1}) to ({2}, {3}).", startRowIdx, startColIdx, endRowIdx, endColIdx)); 
        Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range(topleftCell, bottomrightCell);
        Excel.Interior interior = range.Interior;
        interior.ColorIndex = XLColor.PERIWINKLE; //JUST HIGHLIGHTS RANGE FOR NOW.
        //range.Merge(across);

        //Cleanup
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(interior);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(bottomrightCell);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(topleftCell);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cells);
    }
```

In the code above, I select the cells I want by swapping the columns and rows.  This, contrary to what I expected, results in the desired behavior, but it contradicts the MSDN documentation:

[MSDN Worksheet.Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567.aspx)

In the MSDN documentation they give an example where the row is listed first, then the column follows after.

**So my question is this... which is correct?**
Should the **row** be first, or should the **column** be first?
When I modify my code to be consisten with the MSDN documentation, the highlighted cells are transposed.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then when you use say `cells[1][2]` then it means `A2` In such a case, Column comes first and then the row. If you write it as `cells[1,2]` then you will get `B2` In this case, Row comes first and then the Column.

Comment: It's the same in Excel-VBA. `?Cells(1)(2).address` in immediate window gives `$A$2` and `?Cells(1,2).address` gives `$B$1` If you feel that I have not understood your query then please re-phrase it for me...

Comment: @SiddharthRout what the OP is claiming does not seem to be possible in C#.

Comment: @Varocarbas: It is possible :) Try this `Excel.Range topleftCell = cells[1][2];` and then `MessageBox.Show(topleftCell.Address);` See what you get ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Cells[row, col] is possible. What is not possible is Cells[col][row].

Comment: @varocarbas: Like I said... It is... Perhaps [this](http://wikisend.com/download/883292/1.png) will convince you?

Comment: @varocarbas: if you are still not convinced, I can give you the complete code, you can test. ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout we have to be talking about different things... are you rely on interop to connect to Excel?

Comment: @varocarbas: Yup i am using Interop :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I don't understand anything. Please, can you please copy your code (http://pastebin.com/). I would love to understand why I cannot replicate these conditions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37906/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-varocarbas)

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this behaviour (cells[][]) under VS 2008 (with Office 2010)!!! Sorry about this misunderstanding but I wouldn't ever have expected a so big difference between two VS versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then when you use say `cells[1][2]` then it means `A2` In such a case, Column comes first and then the row. If you write it as `cells[1,2]` then you will get `B2`. In this case, Row comes first and then the Column.

It's the same in Excel-VBA. `?Cells(1)(2).address` in immediate window gives `$A$2` and `?Cells(1,2).address` gives `$B$1` If you feel that I have not understood your query then please re-phrase it for me...

Here is the complete code to test it.

**NOTE**: Tested using VS 2010 Ultimate + Excel 2010

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;

Namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Excel.Application xlexcel;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

            object misValue = Missing.Value;
            xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
            xlexcel.Visible = true;

            //~~> Open a File (Change filename as applicable)
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\SomeFile.xlsx",
                         0, true, 5, "", "", true,

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
            "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

            //~~> Set Sheet 1 as the sheet you want to work with
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            Excel.Range cells = xlWorkSheet.Cells;
            Excel.Range topleftCell = cells[1][2];

            MessageBox.Show(topleftCell.Address);

            topleftCell = cells[1,2];

            MessageBox.Show(topleftCell.Address);

            //~~> Once done close and quit Excel
            xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
            xlexcel.Quit();

            //~~> CleanUp
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlexcel);
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just for future readers: I wasn't able to emulate this behaviour range[][] with VS 2008 and Office 2010.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it with VS 2008 and it doesn't work :) But then 2008 is dated ;) Reminds me I need to upgrade this particular version on this pc to 2013!

Comment: If you mean Office 2013, this is not too recommendable (same thing than VS 2012). Last versions tend to be problematic. I have VS 2008, 2010 and 2012; for most of the things I use 2010 or 2008. Actually, 2008 is very reliable (this "problem" has been really shocking to me; never seen such a thing before... but bear in mind that this is not something really important), might have some missing features but it is still much more recommendable than 2012 (from the overall reliability point of view) in my opinion.

Comment: Take a look at this for Office 2013: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918930/removing-command-button-in-microsoft-word-2013-using-vba?noredirect=1#comment27981726_18918930

Comment: What!!?? Seriously?! It is already in alpha?! Well... completely up to you, but I wouldn't build any production app with that. At least, not before getting some SP.

Comment: Yup :) I have to keep up with the latest version for not so obvious reasons.. Of course I wouldn't be building production apps with 2013 RC...

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Thank you very much!  Changing from "[][]" to "[,]" solved the unexpected behavior.  I actually misread the method definition because both those parameters are optional... so I didn't consinder the outermost brackets: "[[arg1],[arg2]]".  Weird thing that they would have two near equal access procedures with exact opposite results!